# Title missing with ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I want something like the swiping pages in the Google Play Store.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    tools:context="com.nielyouri.pluff.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
            android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:background="#33b5e5"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp" />

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.nielyouri.pluff;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    //private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private DayAdapter mDayAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDayAdapter = new DayAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mDayAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.about:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, AboutActivity.class);

                startActivity(intent);

                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

But when i run the app simulated it shows up without the "Pluff" title...

[image]

My fragment and adapter

http://pastebin.com/2utCxSZx

http://pastebin.com/eexzKpb6

Tried multiple things found on the internet, changing xml etc doesn't do the trick.

Comment: Are you using sdk 22 or 23?

Comment: I do not get what you exaclty want but maybe instead using PagerTitleStrip use TagLayout ?

Comment: @ManishJain using 24

Comment: @Rafal on the fist picture, you see the title "Pluff", but in the simulator the title is gone. I want the "Pluff" title and the "object ..." title so i know on what activity i am

Comment: @Yooouuri: I checked your code, its working fine at my end, I was able to see the title (Object1, Object2...). Could you please attach a screenshot ?

Comment: @ManishJain its not the problem i dont see the (Object 1, Object 2..) but i dont see the Pluff title. The problem is the Pluff title is missing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In xml you have to put below Toolbar code for the action bar:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

In java file:

a. extend class with AppCompatActivity

b. you have to put  the below code for set the title:

```
Toolbar mActionBarToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        mActionBarToolbar.setTitle("Pluff");
        setSupportActionBar(mActionBarToolbar);
```

In manifest file you have to set theme for the activity, see below:

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivityPage"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
            >

        </activity>
```